# How to Install Automation Anywhere version 11

Tags: automationanywhere

How do I Install Automation Anywhere version 11?

Every time I click on any link related Automation it navigates to automation anywhere V19 version.

Can anyone help me to install V11 version not V19?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Automation Anywhere V11 installation files from A-People Community.
https://apeople.automationanywhere.com

1. If you don't have an account, create an account on A-People
2. Login to
3. From the top menu, click on Downloads
4. You will find Automation Anywhere Enterprise
5. Download the latest version, or any older

For installation, you can check the documentation page.
https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v11.3/page/enterprise/topics/control-room/install/installation.html#install

Comment: Hi @khaledMostafame  i have tried with this link https://apeople.automationanywhere.com to download v11 but i got credentials in email  related to v19 version. Can you provide link to install v11. i guess AA Team have disabled  version v11 any idea on it.

Comment: @Raj_Maddy can you please follow the above steps? or you can use this link https://automationanywhere.box.com/s/7flthwtuyiua4mcdpf18d533m3k3qnj7

Comment: I m able to install 11.3 version but how to get control room URL:, User name and password now?

Comment: Open the Automation Anywhere Control Room icon on Desktop, it will ask you to create a username and password